# Cooking meat and milk in the microwave

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk, appliances

Would cooking meat and milk in the microwave be prohibited on the biblical level or just a rabbinical level prohibition?

Comment: Together?  A mixture of milk and meat is prohibited on a biblical level, cooked or not.

Comment: yoel: what is your basis for stating this?

Comment: @r' waxman: I learned that deriving any benefit from any combination of otherwise kosher mammal meat and dairy products was forbidden on a biblical level. if I'm wrong, by all means, please explain so I can avoid such a misstatement in the future.

Comment: @yoel eating or deriving benefit from milk and meat is forbidden on a biblical level only when they were cooked together.

Comment: @tom today I learned.

Comment: @yoel It's also only the case with domesticated mammals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consult your local Orthodox rabbi.

But, to possibly point others in the direction of interesting answers, I have heard it argued that a microwave is considered akin to toledat ha-chama. See [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos5_8.htm) and [here](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/shabbat66/13shabbat.htm).

In terms of cooking on Shabbat, there seems to be one understanding that it is merely a shinui (e.g. Rav Moshe Feinstein); and another understanding that it simply is not considered bishul (Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach), which makes for derabanans in certain cases. This distinction is made in regards to the korban Pesach, matza, challah, etcetera. Maybe we can extrapolate from this and extend it to cooking milk and meat, according to the latter opinion? A close examination of the sources would be required.